# Django-tastypie obj_create not working

Tags: python, django, api, debugging, object

```
class ArticleRevisionResource(ModelResource):

    article_id = fields.IntegerField(attribute='article_id')

    class Meta:
        queryset = ArticleRevision.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'articlerevision'
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']


class ArticleResource(ModelResource):
    #revision = fields.ForeignKey(ArticleRevisionResource, 'article')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'article'
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'option', 'put']
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'article_id']

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        print("==========Obj_create method==========")
        title, content = bundle.data['title'], bundle.data['content']
        bundle.obj = ArticleRevision.objects.create(title="lala", content="lulu", article_id=40)
        bundle.obj.save()
        return bundle
```

So the issue is that it doesn't print out `Obj_create` method, but if I put the same debugging print element in `Meta class`, it prints. So what can I do to find out why `obj_create` method isn't working?

Comment: Did you find a solution for the question? I have the same prob. but about obj_delete method.

Comment: @irajjelodari sorry, this is a very old question and I don't have the source code anymore.

Comment: no problem buddy. i have found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to save it like this

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    print("==========Obj_create method==========")
    title, content = bundle.data['title'], bundle.data['content']
    bundle.obj = ArticleRevision(title="lala", content="lulu", article_id=40)
    bundle.obj.save()
    return bundle
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The code you're posting is just as the one I posted, isn't it?

Comment: Thats the same except this line bundle.obj = ArticleRevision(title="lala", content="lulu", article_id=40)

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but that didn't quit do it. In fact - the issue is that the method itself (`obj_create`) isn't launching and that's what I'm trying to debug.

Comment: Have you tried to put the obj_create in the ArticleRevisionResource class?

Comment: I have and yet the results are the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of overriding the obj_create in the tastypie or modelresources is like below:

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    bundle = super(BookingResource, self).obj_create(bundle)
    bundle.obj.save()
    return bundle
```